# I need help to solve this differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want steps to solve this equation : 
$ y''+y=sin(x)$.
 I found the general solution, and im looking for the particular solution!
I tried but I found $ 0 = sin(x).$

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of parameters variation ?

Comment: The driving frequency equals to the natural frequency, so $y_P$ involves $x(A\sin x+B\cos x)$.

Comment: well , that's right but is it the same form of particular solution with y''-y=sin(x)

Comment: @KaliNihon: No, as that has $\pm 1$ as characteristic roots (as frequencies $\pm i$), while the harmonic oscillator has $\pm i$ as characteristic roots.

Comment: I need a work sheet of the famous shapes of particular solutions .. , I searched in the internet but I didnt find a well organized one!!

Answer (score 1):

for the particular solution make the ansatz $$y_P=A\sin(x)+Bx\cos(x)$$ with the real numbers $$A,B$$

Comment: I thought it is : y = Acos(x) + BSin(x)!!

Comment: No, it has to be $y_p=Ax\sin x+Bx\cos x$ as $1$ is an eigenfrequency of the left side (i.e., $\pm i$ are roots of its characteristic polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the homogeneous equation is $\lambda \cos + \mu \sin$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are real numbers. Now, by variating parameters, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ : 
\begin{equation*}
 \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \sin(x) \end{array} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(x) & \sin(x) \\ -\sin(x) & \cos(x) \end{pmatrix} \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} \lambda'(x) \\ \mu'(x) \end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}

Hence, we get :

\begin{equation*}
 \left( \begin{array}{c} \lambda'(x) \\ \mu'(x) \end{array} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(x) & -\sin(x) \\ \sin(x) & \cos(x) \end{pmatrix} \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \sin(x) \end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}

Computing carefully, you should get :

\begin{equation*}
\exists \lambda_0,\mu_o \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, y(x)= \lambda_0 \cos(x) + \mu_0 \sin (x) - \frac{1}{2}x\cos(x)
\end{equation*}